# How to join data.frames with paste() in the 'by' input?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I make this work?

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
               b = 6:10)

test2 <- data.frame(c = 11:15,
                bb = 6:10)

test %>% left_join(test2, by = c(paste0('b', paste(rep('b', 1), collapse = '')) = 'b'))
```

Currently I get the error:
`Error: unexpected '=' in "test %>% left_join(test2, by = c(paste0('b', paste(rep('b', j), collapse = '')) ="`

In the `rep()` function is currently 1 but the idea is to change it to an index later to use the same code for different inputs.

Comment: It's too long for a comment, but not an answer -- try just running your "paste" at the command line. I don't think it it is doing what you think. I'm also not sure what the "=b" is supposed to do but  what you want to generate is "test %>% left_join(test2, by = c("b" = "bb"))"  not c("bb" = "b")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `a = b` syntax for the `by` statement you need to have it within a `c()`, e.g. `by = c(a = b)`, rather than `by = a = b` which will generate a syntax error.

In your case I'd also assign your complicated `paste0` to a variable so the code is more readable.

This should work:

```r
test <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
               b = 6:10)

test2 <- data.frame(c = 11:15,
                bb = 6:10)

col_to_join = c(paste0('b', paste(rep('b', 1), collapse = '')))
test %>% left_join(test2, by = c("b" = col_to_join))
```

Comment: Thank you! The wrong order was just a mistake in this post. Your answer helped figure out the real problem though.

Comment: To be complete, it seems that on the other way `test2 %>% left_join(test, by = c(col_to_join="b"))` does not work. In the help, I noticed the "by" argument must be a named vector, so you can use : `vect_by <- "b" ; names(vect_by) <- col_to_join ; test2 %>% left_join(test, by = vect_by)`

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues, but this code does what you want I think.

```
test %>% left_join(test2, 
   by = c("b" = paste0('b', paste(rep('b', 1), collapse = ''))))
```

First, put the column names in the correct order.
Second, those names need to be inside a vector.
Third, the `c()` around the paste is unneeded.

Comment: Thank you! The c() isn't wrapped around the paste though. Just the by variables were in the wrong order

Comment: My c( connects with the second to last closing bracket though doesn't it?